# Overloading a part of or entire Django app for a specific User

Tags: python, django

I am developing a large Django site where some of the users are going to have specific needs. So I am looking for a way to overload part of a Django app if the user meets specific conditions.

I would prefer to be able to dynamically load a user tailored version of an app, instead of loading the standard app all together.

The idea is all good in theory, but i have no idea how to do this in a clean python/django-esque way, I would also prefer if my urls would remain the same even when an user app is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't (or, at least, it would be fairly tricky and magical).

In longer: apart from performing the checks in the apps themselves, you might want to consider creating a router app which handles the requests, then decides which sub-app should be responsible for them.

If you can give some more details, it would be possible to give a more detailed answer.